# How can a US citizen and a UK citizen marry in the UK?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, weddings

I am a US citizen. My fiancee lives in the UK and we would like to get married in the UK. I understand that a [Marriage Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa) is the thing to apply for in this case.

However, in order to get married, we need to give notice at a register office, which takes a minimum of 28 days processing time. I cannot live with my fiancee for that amount of time, so the plan is to apply for a Marriage Visitor Visa, live together for the week required by the register office, and give notice. I would then return to the US and resume work there.

If I recall correctly, the eventual marriage license is valid for one year. My question is: what happens if we decide to get married outside of the 6 months granted by the marriage visitor visa? Can I simply apply for another separate one to get married? I would assume so since the visa page lists giving notice and getting married as separate points, but could this be considered extending or switching the visa, which is not allowed? I assume the authorities would take a dim view of applying for a 6-month visa straight after the conclusion of the previous one. How soon after could a subsequent visa application be made?

Comment: Where are you planning to settle after you get married?

Comment: We're still deciding at this moment. We figured if we're going to settle in the UK, the plan was for me to leave after marrying on a Marriage Visitor Visa and then reapply for a spousal visa in the future because there are no plans to move to the UK immediately after marriage at this time.

Comment: Why not do the legal formalities in any other country? The actual ceremony can then be done on a regular visa.

Comment: We have considered this. Regardless though, we would like to know if we must marry within the 6 month time frame or if we can use the MVV to give intent and then reapply for it at a later date for the wedding. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than risk issues with getting another MVV, consider returning to the UK very briefly after 28 days for a legal marriage. You can hold a reception, go on a honeymoon etc. later.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan since one can neither give notice of marriage, nor marry, on a standard visitor visa, doesn't that come straight back to the OP needing two MVVs?

Comment: @MadHatter Is the MVV only single entry?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I am sorry, I see now more clearly what you propose: to use a single MVV to come, give notice, return home, then some 1-5 months later, re-enter to perform the marriage.  Assuming MVVs are multiple entry (I did look on HMG's website, but can as yet find no clear advice), this is doubtless a much better plan than two MVVs (one to give notice, and one to marry).

Comment: Several online forums have reported the MVV being multiple entry. It sounds like it's best to give notice and have the wedding within 6 months of each other. A simple solution in theory, but I work a very strict schedule in healthcare and might not be able to travel to the UK twice within a 6 month period. I appreciate all the feedback we are getting on this subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about UK Marriage Visitor Visa Refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109689/question-about-uk-marriage-visitor-visa-refusal); the question is slightly different but the response addresses all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

For a US or any non-EU citizen to marry a British citizen, a settled person, or one with limited leave, the Family visa is intended category under the [Immigration Rules Appendix FM: family members](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-fm-family-members).

The Marriage Visitor Visa was put into place for couples, both of whom are non-EU nationals, wishing to enter temporarily for the sole purpose of celebrating their wedding and departing the UK.

The [Family visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa) route is much more strenuous, and costlier £1,523, but you may lawfully remain in the country after the marriage and apply for a spouse visa from within the UK. Once granted, the spouse is able to work and, after 5 years, obtain permanent residence (Indefinite Leave to Remain), and is eligible for British nationality. None of those privileges are extended to those with a Marriage Visitor visa.

Comment: The [qualifications for a marriage visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa/eligibility) are perfectly compatible with the US member of a couple who plan to marry in the UK and settle elsewhere.  If you can provide evidence of a similar case in which the visa was denied despite the ECO accepting the couple's stated intentions to settle elsewhere, I will reverse my downvote.  The question you linked to above is not similar enough: the application was not internally consistent, and the ECO was not satisfied that the applicant would leave the UK.